# TSQL Replace all non a-z/A-Z characters with an empty string

Tags: t-sql

I would like to take a field and replace all characters that are not between a-z and A-Z with "".

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create a `CLR` stored procedure to do the regular expression replacement.  Here's an article on that topic:
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/04/27/SQL-2005-Regular-Expression-Replace.aspx

Then you could do something like this:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET col1 = dbo.RegExReplace(col1, '[^A-Za-z]','');
```

EDIT:
Since `CLR` isn't an option, check out [this](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/tsql-regular-expression-workbench/#fourth) link, there is a `dbo.RegexReplace` function there which is written in t-sql, not CLR. You could use that function in the following manner:

First, you need to run this to enable Ole:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Then create the `dbo.RegexReplace` function given at the link I provided.

Then you can do this:

```
create table your_table(col1 varchar(500))
go

insert into your_table values ('aBCCa1234!!fAkk9943');

update your_table set col1 = dbo.RegexReplace('[^A-Za-z]','',col1,1,1);

select * from your_table

Result:
aBCCafAkk
```

Comment: .NET CLR isn't an option.  Thanks though.  Needs to be in pure SQL

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a UDF (user defined function) and then use it in your queries:

- http://www.sqlteam.com/article/regular-expressions-in-t-sql (Uses COM)
- http://blogs.msdn.com/khen1234/archive/2005/05/11/416392.aspx (Uses COM)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx (Uses CLR)

Then do a query similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE find_regular_expression(myCol, '[^a-zA-Z]')
```

It also appears the there may be more native support in later versions of SQL Server, certainly 2008 R2, through the mdq.RegexMatches function (Part of Master Data Services).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633829(SQL.105).aspx

Comment: But he needs to replace the matched pattern, not just find it.

Answer (score 0):

With the introduction of the `TRANSLATE()` function in SQL Server 2017, this is now easy to do without any slow looping UDF's or complex CLR's

### Fast Native SQL Server 2017+ Solution

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES ('Hello th!s is a te$t')
            ,('An$#oth!:er test 1234567890')
    ) AS A(String)
/*First find all non a-z characters by removing all a-z characters*/
CROSS APPLY (SELECT nonAZChars = REPLACE(TRANSLATE(String,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',REPLICATE(' ',26)),' ','')) AS B
/*Translate non a-z characters to random character "|" and then remove all "|"*/
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CleanString = REPLACE(TRANSLATE(String,nonAZChars,REPLICATE('|',LEN(nonAZChars))),'|','')) AS C
```

### Results

| String | nonAZChars | CleanString |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hello th!s is a te$t | !$ | Hello ths is a tet |
| An$#oth!:er test 1234567890 | $#!:1234567890 | Another test |