# Select query that displays Joined words separately, not using a function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I require a select query that adds a space to the data based on the placement of the capital letters i.e. 'HelpMe' using this query would be displayed as 'Help Me' . Note i cannot use a stored function to do this the it must be done in the query itself. The Data is of variable length and query must be in SQL. Any Help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What flavor of SQL?  I'm thinking something like a regular expression in the query might do it...

Comment: Are there no spaces now?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use user defined function for this until MS give us support for regular expressions. Solution would be something like:

```
SELECT col1, dbo.RegExReplace(col1, '([A-Z])',' \1') FROM Table
```

Aldo this would produce leading space that you can remove with TRIM.

Replace regular expresion function:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/378520

About dbo.RegexReplace you can read at:

[TSQL Replace all non a-z/A-Z characters with an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374594/tsql-replace-all-non-a-z-a-z-characters-with-an-empty-string)

Comment: Cannot use a stored function.  RegExReplace is a stored function - is it not?

Comment: Quick question can i make this part of a select i.e select  col1= dbo.RegExReplace(col1, '([A-Z])',' \1') as FN where col1='WhatEver' , I dont want the table to be permanently updated to reflect the space only when displaying should it reflect it. in other worlds using the select it should display 'What Ever' , however in the DB it will remain 'WhatEver' is this possible?

Comment: I do not have MSSQL 2012 so i can not try this but it is in documentation. Try this:
select dbo.RegExReplace(col1, '([A-Z])',' \1') where col1='WhatEver'

Comment: It is not built in on my install.  And I don't see it listed as a built in function in the docs.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174318(v=sql.105).aspx  Both the links in your answer indicate it is not built in.

Answer (score 0):

Assume if you are using `Oracle` RDBMS, you use the following,

`REGEX_REPLACE`

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('ILikeToWatchCSIMiami',
           '([A-Z.])', ' \1')
           AS RX_REPLACE
      FROM dual
;
```

Managed to get this output: * [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc5de/1)

But as you see it doesn't treat well on words such as `CSI` though.