# Removing non numeric characters from a value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to remove various characters from a value to only get/display the numeric characters.
I can get results such as

```
value1: 162246xx
value2: =W035268
value3: +034567
value4: =<E04569
```

but only am interested and getting:
    value1: 162246
    value2: 035268
    value3: 034567
    value4: 04569

What type of query can I run to retrieve all the values from column X excluding non numerical characters within the value?
Thank you.

Comment: Related - [TSQL Replace all non a-z/A-Z characters with an empty string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374594/tsql-replace-all-non-a-z-a-z-characters-with-an-empty-string)

Comment: Though it would be better if I mentioned that I'm querying the table and not attempting to modify the way the data is stored.  I just want to retrieve the data and get results without the non numeric characters.  thanks

Comment: So don't run the `UPDATE` statement - perform the `replace` within your `SELECT` so that the values that come out are stripped of the non-numeric characters.

Comment: This page might help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52315/t-sql-trim-nbsp-and-other-non-alphanumeric-characters

Comment: So if I have the following:

Comment: "Select h.value from hobservation h where h.findingAbbr = a_findingB" how do I add the function to make sure h.value displays only the numeric characters?  All this is new to me and I’m not understanding the links provided to me.  Thanks in advance.